# Angular- Couldnot parse json response in front-end

Tags: json, angularjs

I made an httpRequest fetch some items using following code:

```
factory.getBanners = function() {
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://localhost:2100/v1/items/getBanners'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      console.log(response);
      return response;
    });
  };
```

In controller I handled it as following:

```
store.controller('bannerCtrl', ['$scope', 'productService', function($scope, productService){
  $scope.init = function() {
    $scope.banners = productService.getBanners();
  }
  $scope.init();
}]);
```

In front end I tried to display data using

```
<div ng-controller="bannerCtrl">
    <div data-ng-repeat="banner in banners">
        <li> {{banner.bannerAltText}} </li>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't display anything. Neither it gives any error on console. How can I resolve this issue. Here banners is an array whose each element contains bannerAltText.

Comment: try `response.data`.  also, your factory isn't returning anything, only your `.then()` is.

Comment: If you are getting data in console, expand it and see the structure of data.

Comment: yes i expanded the data and i can see under data object, my required array is there. So i returned response.data. But still it can't parse

Comment: Can you update your question with data you got in console. Expand it and copy paste here.

Comment: @Ved The data is not the issue, the structure of the code is wrong (as both answers to the question point out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getBanners`-function does not work the way you think it does. It returns nothing. The `return` statement in the `then` function only returns from that `then`-function, not from `getBanners`. The problem is that you are trying to use an asynchonous function in a synchronous way. Instead make `getBanners` return a promise:

```
factory.getBanners = function() {
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:2100/v1/items/getBanners'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        return response.data;
    });
};
```

And use that promise in your controller:

```
$scope.init = function() {
    productService.getBanners().then(function(banners) {
        $scope.banners = banners;
    });
}
$scope.init();
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

A `return` in a in `.then()` will be a promise, rather than the data. here is a better way to construct your code

```
factory.getBanners = function() {
    return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://localhost:2100/v1/items/getBanners'
    });
  };
```

.

```
store.controller('bannerCtrl', ['$scope', 'productService', function($scope, productService){
  $scope.init = function() {
    productService.getBanners()
    .then(function(response) {$scope.banners = response.data});
  }
  $scope.init();
}]);
```